# react dispatch returns promise instead of plain object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Dispatch in container for some reason returns promise instead of an object, or so web browser console tells me:

`mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(OverviewShortComponent) must return a plain object. Instead received [object Promise].`

Container in question:

```
// OverviewShortContainer.js
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        overview: state.overview,
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        const data = dispatch(homeOperations.fetchOverviewSummary());
        return data;
    };

    const OverviewShortContainer = connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(OverviewShortComponent)

    // homeOperations.js
    const fetchOverviewSummary = () => {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(actions.fetchOverviewBegin());
            return fetch('http://localhost:8080/overview/summary')
                .then(handleErrors)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(json => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify("json="+JSON.stringify(json)));
                    dispatch(actions.fetchOverviewSuccess(json));
                })
        }
    }

    // index.js
    const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger);
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware);

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
    registerServiceWorker();
```

Attaching browser log, where you can see that begin/success actions are dispatched and data retrieved, so why is this happening? What am I missing? (I am new to react, so that might be a lot).

[image: browser console log:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you're actually invoking dispatch and the action itself in the mapDispatchToProps (which will return a promise, not the object `connect` is expecting). I would just write that in the following way:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchOverviewSummary: homeOperations.fetchOverviewSummary
}
```

This is the simpler and recommended way to bind actions to your connected component.

Answer (score 0):

`mapDispatchToProps` has to return the method, as it connects redux actions (methods) with component. Example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return({
        fetchOverviewSummary: () => {dispatch(homeOperations.fetchOverviewSummary())}
    })
};
```

Afterwards, you can call `fetchOverviewSummary()` in your connected component.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is not right

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        const data = dispatch(homeOperations.fetchOverviewSummary());
        return data;
 };
```

**mapDispatchToProps** is suppose to return an **Object** with keys which can then be used to perform actions. For ex: in case **fetchOverviewSummary** is to be called from within component it should be declared like below:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            fetchOverviewSummary: () => {dispatch(homeOperations.fetchOverviewSummary())}
        }
 };
```

and then it is called as:

```
this.props.fetchOverviewSummary()
```